# How do I set fetchSize in memory db?

Tags: mysql, junit, mybatis, hsqldb

Recently I'm working on Junit to test Dao related code with hsqldb(2.3.3). The system is using mybatis for data persistence.

In mybatisXXsql.xml, there's "fetchSize" property in select statement like:

```
<select ... resultSetType="FORWARD_ONLY" fetchSize="-2147483648">
    ...
</select>
```

While we calling tested the sql with hsqldb, it showed following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument in JDBC call
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.outOfRangeArgument(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setFetchSize(Unknown Source)
```

I checked seems it doesn't support "fetchSize" in memory db, could anyone give some advice how could I test this sql part?

Answer (score 2):

Negative `fetchSize` is [not supported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) by JDBC. Here's description of the exceptions that `setFetchSize` throws:

> SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement or the condition rows >= 0 is not satisfied.

The reason of the error is that fetch size is incorrect (`outOfRangeArgument` in stack trace also suggests this).

mysql driver does support `Integer.MIN_INT` as fetch size to specify that result set is in streaming mode:

> The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch size of Integer.MIN_VALUE serves as a signal to the driver to stream result sets row-by-row. After this, any result sets created with the statement will be retrieved row-by-row.

mybatis itself does not allow to paramtrize `fetchSize` in mapper configuration.

You need to use some technics to override the configuration via `AspectJ` or `PowerMock`. With `PowerMock` you can use `PowerMock.stub` to do something like this before you invoke the method that executes the query:

```
PowerMock.stub(
   PowerMock.method(
       org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.class,
       "getFetchSize"
   )
).toReturn(1);
```

This way when mybatis will create a `Statement` it will use mocked value for `fetchSize`

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So how can I test this part or can I mock this part to reset fetchSize?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an option how to solve this